# SQL SERVER - get 0 instead of now rows when doesnt match criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'll start by saying that im not an expert in SQL, much less SQL SERVER.

I'm trying to execute the query bellow:

Basically what it does is, for each day in between a start date and a end date
get me some data and insert it in a table variable.

```
BEGIN

declare @sdate datetime = dateadd(day, -10, getdate())
declare @edate datetime = getdate()
declare @max int = datediff(day, @sdate, @edate)
declare @sday int = cast(day(@sdate) as int)
declare @i int = 1;

declare @Days2 table (
    [sending_id] varchar(255) not null,
    [day] datetime not null,
    [conversions] int not null
)

while @i <= @max
BEGIN
    declare @ssdate datetime = cast(dateadd(day, (@max - @i) * -1 , @edate) as date)
    declare @eedate datetime = cast(dateadd(day, ((@max - @i) * -1) + 1 , @edate)as date)

    INSERT into @Days2 ([sending_id], [day], [conversions])
    select CS.send_id, @ssdate as [date], ISNULL(count(*), 0) as day_conversion
    from campaigns_history CH
    LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_sends CS ON CS.campaign_historyID = CH.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN c C ON C.subid = convert(varchar(255), CS.id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN conversions_keygen CK ON CK.campaignID = CS.id AND cast(CK.genkey as varchar(255)) = C.clickid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lead_feed LF ON LF.leadID = CK.leadID
    WHERE
        CH.id = 19
        and isnumeric(C.subid) <> 0
        and C.tstamp > @ssdate
        and C.tstamp < @eedate
    group by CS.send_id

    SET @i = @i+1
END

select * from @Days2

END
```

what im trying to achieve is something like this:

```
sending_id | days        | conversions
---------------------------------------
send-1     |  2017-08-01 | 1
---------------------------------------
send-1     |  2017-08-02 | 0            -- the problem is here
---------------------------------------
send-2     |  2017-08-01 | 1   
---------------------------------------
send-2     |  2017-08-02 | 4
```

but i get this:

```
sending_id | days        | conversions
---------------------------------------
send-1     |  2017-08-01 | 1
---------------------------------------
send-2     |  2017-08-01 | 1   
---------------------------------------
send-2     |  2017-08-02 | 4
```

I know this happens because of this -> `C.subid = CS.id`,  `C.tstamp >= ...` and `C.tstamp <= ...` meaning that theres no rows matching this criteria.

But I need to get that 0 row too!

Help me please.

thanks in advance and happy programming!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track using your `left join`, but your current `where` clause is preventing the blank rows from being counted. Move your conditions to the join condition like so:

```
select CS.send_id, @ssdate as [date], count(c.subid) as day_conversion
from campaigns_history CH
LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_sends CS ON CS.campaign_historyID = CH.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c C ON C.subid = convert(varchar(255), CS.id)
    and isnumeric(C.subid) <> 0
    and C.tstamp > @ssdate
    and C.tstamp < @eedate
LEFT OUTER JOIN conversions_keygen CK ON CK.campaignID = CS.id 
  AND cast(CK.genkey as varchar(255)) = C.clickid
LEFT OUTER JOIN lead_feed LF ON LF.leadID = CK.leadID
WHERE
    CH.id = 19
group by CS.send_id
```

Also switch out `ISNULL(count(*), 0)` for `count(c.subid)` so you don't get a count of `1` when `c.subid` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks @SqlZim, it fixed my problem.